problems between mysql and .env
i have server.js
const mysql = require('mysql2')
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
})

and .env
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_USER=root
DB_PASSWORD=my password
DB_DATABASE=my db name


i work with database client JDBC in vscode
and there is the problem
Error: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Packet.asError 
  code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
  errno: 1045,
  sqlState: '28000',
  sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)",
  sql: undefined

also i can connect to my db if i dont use env variables.

Its not the error of your code. Its due to mysql configuration. " sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)" Because you haven't set password for your mysql database. just remove "my password" against DB_PASSWORD in your .env and try again.

i think its same but now
sqlMessage: "Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

What if you try user root instead of user @

I don't see you loading in the env file in your code.
